# How to change numbering of questions in exam mode?

Tags: exam

Basically our exam department restricted to put five question each of 15 marks. each question have three sub parts each of five marks ( should be denoted by (a), (b), (c)) and 100% option means these has to be three sub parts each of 5 marks ( compulsorily denoted by (p), (q), (r)). this compulsion to keep uniformity and avoid mistakes in question numbers.

I want something like below but my program fail to give this. Here I am fail to get sub part notations (p), (q) and (r) :

1. (a) Some text  (5)

   (b) Some text  (5)

   (c) Some text  (5)

   ```
                    OR
   ```

   (p) Some text  (5)

   (q) Some text  (5)

   (r) Some text  (5)
2. (a) Some text  (5)

   (b) Some text  (5)

   (c) Some text  (5)

   ```
                    OR
   ```

   (p) Some text  (5)

   (q) Some text  (5)

   (r) Some text  (5)

Program written by me:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb,amsfonts,color,mathtools}

\usepackage[a4paper,bindingoffset=0 cm, left=2cm, right=3cm, top=1.5cm, bottom=2cm, footskip=0.5cm]{geometry}

\parindent=0pt

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\pointsinrightmargin

\question 

\begin{parts}

\part[5]

\part[5]

\part[5]

\end{parts}

\begin{center} \textbf{\large{OR}} \end{center}

\begin{parts}

\part[5]

\part[5]

\part[5]

\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please provide a complete [example document](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that reproduces the above output, and clarify how the numbering should be changed exactly

Comment: I have edited my query with proper explaination. Kidly go through it. waiting for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example. Just renew the commands on partno and partlabel for the appearance. Set the `partno` counter to the number of the desired letter. Note that you can go up to 25.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{exam}

\renewcommand{\thepartno}{\alph{partno}}
\renewcommand{\partlabel}{(\thepartno)}

\pointsinrightmargin

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question Some text

\begin{parts}
\part[5] Some text
\part[5] Some text
\part[5] Some text
\setcounter{partno}{15} % <- change the partno counter
\part[5] Some text
\part[5] Some text
\part[5] Some text
\end{parts}

\question Some text

\begin{parts}
\part[5] Some text
\part[5] Some text
\part[5] Some text
\setcounter{partno}{15} % <- change the partno counter
\part[5] Some text
\part[5] Some text
\part[5] Some text
\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sir, My concern is different. I wanted to change parts numbers from a,b,c to p,q,r. I have edited my query with proper explaination. kindly go through it.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I hope I understand your question now

Comment: Sir, Thanks a lot and I wanted to appreciate your timely response and dedication towards helping new learners. Thank you so much.